# Create a 7-day rolling mean by Group

Tags: r, function, data.table, moving-average

I want to create a 7-day rolling mean for a daily physical training load over a year calculated for each athlete in a training group.

The data set is called 'daily.load'. The vectors are: 'Date', 'Name', 'Total.Load'

The ideal end result would be a rolling 7-day mean for 'Total.Load' as a fourth vector called 'Rolling.Average' in the 'daily.load' data set.

I am attempting to do this with rollmean but I'm getting stuck when it comes to getting the function to generate the rolling mean by athlete.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `by` argument in `data.table`, so calculating the rolling mean by athlete should not be a problem. Below is a reproducible example, where I calculated the rolling average with `rollmean`. Also note that `RcppRoll::roll_mean` is probably way faster than `zoo::rollmean`.

```
# load packages
require(data.table)
require(zoo)
# create data
Ndays <- 100
Nnames <- 5
daily.load <- data.table(Date = rep(Sys.Date() - seq.int(Ndays, 1), times = Nnames), 
                         Name = rep(LETTERS[seq(Nnames)], each=Ndays), 
                         Total.Load = rnorm(Ndays*Nnames, 100, 5))
setkey(daily.load, "Name", "Date")
# calculate rolling average by Name
daily.load[, Rolling.Average := rollmean(Total.Load, 7, fill = NA), by = Name]
```

Comment: Thanks for this response.  I think when I ran this command it looked for 100 days and 5 athletes but these values will differ between and within groups.  I'm wondering if you know a method to use the by group argument in data.table that permits the command to move through the data set and determine the length of Ndays and Nnames vs. me specifying the length? Does this require a function to do this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm new to R and this has stumped me.

Comment: The 100 days and 5 athletes was just used for generating data. The calculation of the rolling average does not need this. You should be able to run the command on your data.

Comment: I ran this two different ways both including the commands Ndays<-100 and Nnames<- 5, and without.  It generates a data table where the athletes names have been replaced with the characters A through E, and has generated 100 data points per subject.  It has also overwritten the variable Total.Load with a new value (not sure what it is).  I think I might be missing something.  Any thoughts?  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I also ran this using the final command you suggested: daily.load[, Rolling.Average := rollmean(Total.Load, 7, fill = NA), by = Name]; it generates the following error message: Error in `[.data.frame`(daily.load, , `:=`(Rolling.Average, rollmean(Total.Load,  : 
  unused argument (by = Name)

Comment: That final error message suggests that you actually have a `data.frame` instead of a `data.table`. You can use `setDT(daily.load)` to turn it into a `data.table`.

Comment: This makes sense and I was able to get the newly set 'data table' to generate the variable Rolling.Average.  I can't quite make sense of the answer though.  Here's an example for one subject's first four data points: Date<-c(2014-05-19, 2014-05-20, 2014-05-21, 2014-05-22); Name<-c(DoeJ, DoeJ, DoeJ, DoeJ); Total.Load<-c(1320, 405, 885, 360); Rolling.Average<-c(NA, NA, NA, 668.5714).  Hope this makes sense.  I would have expected NAs to be generated for the first 6 data points (not first 4), followed by the numerical mean of those first 7 data points.  Third time is the charm I hope. Thanks!

Comment: `rollmean` has an `align` argument. By default, it centers the index of the result compared to the rolling window. You can use `align = "right"` to get the desired behavior: `rollmean(Total.Load, 7, fill = NA, align = "right")`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Shadow.  The exact code that worked was:

setDT(daily.load)

daily.load[, Rolling.Average := rollmean(Total.Load, 7, fill = NA, align="right"), by = Name]

The align="right" vs. align="centre" is a great option.  Also remember for R neophytes to distinguish whether or not you have a data table or a data frame.